# Error al querer ir por segunda vez desde un OnActivityResult a un fragment

Tags: onactivityresult

Estoy generando pagos con mercado pago en android studio, lo que me esta pasando es que la primera vez que hago un pago y me devuelve que fue exitoso, en el onActivityResult puedo ir bien al fragment donde sigo con los demas pasos, pero la segunda vez que quiero hacer un pago sin cerrar la app ni nada, al poner continuar en mercado pago que es donde despues de eso me deberia llevar al fragment se me cierra la app.

En el primer fragment abro mercado pago

```
new MercadoPagoCheckout.Builder(public_key, preference_id).build()
            .startPayment(getActivity(), REQUEST_CODE);
```

En el activity principal.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    Log.d("requestCode", String.valueOf(requestCode));
    Log.d("resultCode", String.valueOf(resultCode));
    Log.d("data", String.valueOf(data));
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == MercadoPagoCheckout.PAYMENT_RESULT_CODE) {
            final Payment payment = (Payment) data.getSerializableExtra(MercadoPagoCheckout.EXTRA_PAYMENT_RESULT);
            PaymentData paymentData = JsonUtil.getInstance().fromJson(data.getStringExtra("paymentData"), PaymentData.class);
            Log.d("payment", String.valueOf(payment));
            Log.d("paymentData", String.valueOf(paymentData));

            String status_pago = payment.getPaymentStatus();
            String medio_pago = payment.getPaymentMethodId();
            String tipo_medio_elegido = payment.getPaymentTypeId();


            SharedPreferences preferences = this.getSharedPreferences("bundle", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            String idCondVenta = preferences.getString("idCondVenta", null);
            String nroCupon = preferences.getString("nroCupon", null);
            String idTarjeta = preferences.getString("idTarjeta", null);
            String importeTotal = preferences.getString("importeTotal", null);
            String response=preferences.getString("productos" , "");

            if (status_pago.equals("approved")){
                Toast.makeText(this, "Pago aprobado!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("idCondVenta", idCondVenta);
                bundle.putString("nroCupon", nroCupon);
                bundle.putString("idTarjeta", idTarjeta);

                bundle.putDouble("importeTotal", Double.parseDouble(importeTotal));
                bundle.putString("productos_mp", response);
                bundle.putString("paymentTypeId", tipo_medio_elegido);
                bundle.putString("paymentMethodId", medio_pago);
                bundle.putString("status", status_pago);
                bundle.putString("statusDetail", payment.getPaymentStatusDetail());
                bundle.putString("transactionAmount", String.valueOf(payment.getTransactionAmount()));
                bundle.putString("operationType", String.valueOf(payment.getOperationType()));
                bundle.putString("id", String.valueOf(payment.getId()));
                bundle.putString("dateCreated", String.valueOf(payment.getDateCreated()));
                bundle.putString("dateApproved", String.valueOf(payment.getDateApproved()));
                bundle.putString("currencyId", String.valueOf(payment.getCurrencyId()));
                Log.d("bundle", String.valueOf(bundle));

                Fragment fragment = new EmitirComprobante_Fragment2();
                //FragmentManager fm = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragment.setArguments(bundle);
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainFragment,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
                //fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainFragment, fragment).addToBackStack("formulario").commit();

            }else{
                Log.d("pago","no aprov");
                Toast.makeText(this, "Resultado del pago: "+payment.getPaymentStatus(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            //Done!
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            if (data != null && data.getExtras() != null
                    && data.getExtras().containsKey(MercadoPagoCheckout.EXTRA_ERROR)) {
                final MercadoPagoError mercadoPagoError =
                        (MercadoPagoError) data.getSerializableExtra(MercadoPagoCheckout.EXTRA_ERROR);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Error: "+ mercadoPagoError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //((TextView) findViewById(R.id.mp_results)).setText("Error: " + mercadoPagoError.getMessage());
                //Resolve error in checkout
            } else {
                //Resolve canceled checkout
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Y el LogCat no me da ninguna error

```
2020-12-23 15:09:49.837 30239-30239/com.vg.ffV/FA: onActivityCreated
2020-12-23 15:09:49.839 30239-30268/com.vg.ffV/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-12-23 15:09:49.853 30239-30268/com.vg.ffD/FA: Logging event (FE): screen_view(_vs), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, firebase_previous_class(_pc)=ReviewAndConfirmActivity, firebase_previous_id(_pi)=6237663741496883305, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=PaymentResultActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=6237663741496883306}]
2020-12-23 15:09:49.866 30239-30268/com.vg.ffV/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-12-23 15:09:49.866 30239-30268/com.vg.ffV/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2020-12-23 15:09:49.867 30239-30268/com.vg.ffV/FA: Activity resumed, time: 1447848894
2020-12-23 15:09:49.929 30239-30268/com.vg.ffD/FA: Connected to remote service
2020-12-23 15:09:49.929 30239-30268/com.vg.ffV/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
2020-12-23 15:09:51.926 30239-30268/com.vg.ffV/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 2074
2020-12-23 15:09:51.935 30239-30268/com.vg.ffV/FA: Activity paused, time: 1447850968
2020-12-23 15:09:51.938 30239-30268/com.vg.ffD/FA: Logging event (FE): user_engagement(_e), Bundle[{firebase_event_origin(_o)=auto, engagement_time_msec(_et)=2074, firebase_screen_class(_sc)=PaymentResultActivity, firebase_screen_id(_si)=6237663741496883306}]
2020-12-23 15:09:52.060 30239-30274/com.vg.ffD/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x730c459200 (StateListDrawable) with handle 0x73272ea2a0
```

Comment: Si se cierra tu aplicación debe mostrarse un error en el LogCat, busca donde diga "Caused by"

Comment: @Elenasys no me sale eso tampoco

Comment: Puede ser que sea por los datos que estoy mandando a el siguiente fragment? ya que si no hago esa llamada al fragment me hace los pasos como deberia.

Comment: Es que pueden ser varias cosas si no se tiene algún mensaje en el LogCat, de hecho si se cierra y no se muestra error en el LogCat me parece lo más extraño.

Comment: Si entiendo, nose porque no me tira ningun error, y ademas si no quiero ir a otro fragment despues de esa ejecucion tambien anda todo bien, me parece muy raro